# Chrome extension getting rejected although permission is required

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a chrome extension which is getting rejected because according to them I do not need the tabs permission I am asking for. However, I have looked over my code and my chrome extension would not work without it. I have even tried my chrome extension without the permission and it failed. I am using tabs when doing things such as `chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removeInfo)`, `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)`, and more which all require tabs permissions. Can someone help me understand why it might be getting rejected? Or if there is a work around.

The funny part is, that my original extension using tabs permission was accepted, but when I sent a revised version in, they rejected that although the changes had nothing to do with tabs.

The specific reasoning I got:

```
Violation reference ID: Purple Potassium
Violation: The following permission(s) need not be requested for the methods/properties implemented by the item:
tabs
How to rectify: Remove the above permission(s). The properties used by the items will continue to function even without requesting these permissions.
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#manifest), you don't need the `tabs` permission unless you require access to the `url`, `title` or `favIconUrl` properties of the tab. Without seeing the code, we cannot tell if that is the case.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko so how exactly do I get tabs id and all without tabs permissions. Some sample code of what I am doing is ```chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabid, removeInfo) {
    if(tabid == tabId) {
        console.log("closed tab");
        stop();
    }
});``` which is changing flags based on a tab being open or closed. Also over here, I am using tabs.query to send my content script the specific tab to get some dom data from.

Comment: No code shown requires the `tabs` permission. You said the extension failed when you removed that permission. What was the error?

Comment: @IvánNokonoko My extension is meant to work on certain sites for like releases of items. So I need to wait until the next release to re-attempt it without permissions. Until then, I can't properly test it sadly. So I'll get back here if it still is causing problems after I test it again.

Comment: As the first comment says you don't need `tabs` permission to get the tab id. All methods in `chrome.tabs` can be used without the `tabs` permission.